# Diferecia o beneficios de conectar con una clase a base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, mysqli

hoy vengo con una duda muy básica sobre conexión a base de datos ya que no tengo algunos conceptos claros y gustaría saber cual es la diferencia o beneficio de conectarse con la base de datos usando una clase o normalmente.

Es decir cual seria la diferencia de este **codigo**:

```
<?php 
     class conexion {

    /**
    * Gestiona la conexión con la base de datos
    */

    private $dbhost = 'localhost';

    private $dbuser = 'nombre usuario';

    private $dbpass = 'contraseña';

    private $dbname = 'base de datos';

    public function conexion () {

    /**
    * @return object link_id con la conexión
    */

    $conn= new mysqli($this->dbhost,$this->dbuser,$this->dbpass,$this->dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

    echo "Error de Connexion ($conn->connect_errno)

    $conn->connect_error\n";

    header('Location: error-conexion.php');

    exit;

    } else {

    return $conn;

    }

    }

    } ?>
```

a solo hacer este código:

```
<?php 


  $conn= new mysqli("localhost","root","","DB");

  if($conn){

  echo"conexion fail"; 
}else{

    echo"conexion success";
}

?>
```

Más que una pregunta, es una duda, osea ¿Por que el primer código seria mejor?

Espero me puedan aclarar esta simple duda y disculpen por la ignorancia pero hasta ahora no le había dado tanta importancia a la conexión con la base de datos, gracias!

Comment: Cuando necesites más conexiones solo llamas esa clase y realiza la conexión y no la creas nuevamente a mano, además cuando cambies de base de datos solo es necesario cambia los parámetros en esa clase y no en cada una de las clases que hayas creado si lo haces a mano.

Comment: osea a la hora de yo hacer la conexion con este codigo `<?php 
  $conn= new mysqli("localhost","root","","DB");
  if($conn){

  echo"conexion fail"; 
}else{

    echo"conexion success";
}

?>` lo guardo en un archivo llamado `conexion.php` y luego si nececito llamar a la base de datos en otros archivos hago lo siguiente `include"conexion.php";` tedria que hacer lo mismo si me conecto con el primer codigo osea incluilo si en otro archivo si lo necesito es decir `include"conexion.php";` so cual es la diferencia?

Comment: Si necesitas hace un proceso con tu base de datos en una clase lo que tienes que hacer es llamar a tu clase conexion.php con un require_once('conexion.php');  y realizas tu consulta y lo que necesites.

Comment: y la otra forma es crear nuevamente la conexión en tu clase donde necesites hacer un proceso con tu base de datos.

Comment: es decir con el primer codigo seria `include"conexion.php";` y con el segundo `require_once('conexion.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear tu conexión en un archivo que se llame conexión.php donde pongas los datos de tu base de datos, ejemplo:

```
$password='root';
$servidor='localhost';
$bd_name = 'asteriskcdrdb';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die('No se pudo conectar: ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $bd_name) or die('No se pudo seleccionar la base de datos'. mysqli_error());
```

Y llamarla en tu clase donde requieras hacer un proceso con tu base de datos como puede ser un insert, update …
Ejmplo en tu archivo agregar_usuario.php invocas tu conexion.

```
require_once('conexion.php');
```

Y la otra forma es crear nuevamente la conexión en tu clase agregar_usuario.php cosa que no es nada práctico ya que no estas trabajando con programación orientada a objetos. Al trabajar con programación orientada a objetos reutilizas mucho código.

Answer (score -2):

Una buena practica y el por que se usa una clase para representar la conexión con la base de datos es poder realizar *una unica conexión a la bd* en toda la aplicación y representarla mediante una clase singleton es decir que no sea instanciada nuevamente cada vez que sea usada sino que exista de forma permanente durante todo el ciclo de vida de la aplicación.

Otro motivo muy común en lenguajes orientados a objetos es poder representar la conexión a base de datos como un objeto el cual pueda ser integrado a arquitecturas mas complejas de forma facil y ordenada, como multiples conexiones a datos o crear interfaces de conexión que hoy sea hacia una base de datos y mañana hacia un api rest.

Uno ultimo que se me ocurre es para facilitar el testing automático, puedes llamar a la conexión como una instancia durante la ejecución de un test puntual y encapsular las acciones como conexión desconexión y consulta bajo metodos de instancia.